# Let $A \subset X$ metric space. Then $d(x,A) = 0$ if and only if $x\in \overline{A}?$

Tags: metric-spaces

I am trying to prove this. I did not find in any book.

I was making some exercises where I had to prove that if $A$ is closed and $x\not\in A$ then $d(x,A) >0.$
Because of the condition "being closed" I asked myself: $d(x,A) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x \in \overline{A}?$

It is true? Any hints to prove? Any references?

Thanks!

Comment: Related : [Closure of a subset in a metric space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12077/closure-of-a-subset-in-a-metric-space)

Answer (score 1):

Sketch:

Suppose $d(x,A)=r>0$, then the open ball $B_x(r/2)$ does int intersect $A$, so $x$ is not in the closure of $A$.

Suppose $d(x,A)=0$.  Then for all $n$, we can can find $a_n\in A$ such that $d(x,a_n)<\frac{1}{n}$.  For any open set $U$ containing $x$, there is a ball $B_x(r)\subseteq U$.  Let $n>\frac{1}{r}$, then $a_n\in U$, so $U\cap A\not=\emptyset$.  Therefore, $x$ is in the closure of $A$.